I do not have a degree certificate, does a final transcript count as a proof of degree completion?
For both my MA and BA degrees, the universities have not yet had a convocation to confer the degree. I'm confused as to what I should put in my grad applications for PhD; that I have earned my degree (since I have passed all my courses and have a final transcript at hand, with the final CGPA) and use the final transcript as proof, or say that I have not earned the degree yet? Should I select "Degree Conferred" or "Degree Expected"? Some universities that I'm applying to have a section to upload the 'diploma' alongside the transcript, albeit most don't -- really confused as to what I should do.

This is somewhat country dependent. In what country did you earn your degrees, and in what country are the schools where you are applying?

Some universities put the degree on each transcript. Look at your transcript carefully to see if your degree is entered there. It is likely to be very small and abbreviated, ed, AB or MS or PhD.

In my experience, the physical degree certificate is just a nice thing to hang on the wall.  Anyone who cares about whether or not you have the degree is going to want to see transcripts which show that you have earned that degree.

(My assumption, in the above comment, is that "final transcript" means a transcript which shows that the degree has been earned.  If that assumption is in error, then you may want to edit the question to explain what, exactly, you mean by a "final transcript".)

@XanderHenderson in Romania for example, we got: a fancy but legally useless piece of paper to hang on the wall, the "real" diploma which is ugly but full of personal information regarding the student and the results from their graduation exam, a piece of paper as temporary proof  instead of the diploma, with the same info (the diploma did not arrive yet), and Transcripts of Records which contains information about every subject taught during University, as well as some extra info. ToR would be needed only if some Uni would have specific requirements regarding grades, diploma might suffice.

When I was in grad school, I had to apply to graduate (which was accepted), so my graduation had already been accepted months before I went to the convocation. (I finished my thesis at the end of summer and didn't go to the ceremony until December). Did you apply to graduate already and have the application accepted?

@NateEldredge I'm from India, applying to the US for a doctoral program in the humanities.

@DavidSmith The transcripts mention "Date of Result", a "Grade" as pass/fail and or First Class etc. Would that count as date of degree?

@XanderHenderson By final transcript (in my case) means where it clearly states the final CGPA of my bachelor's degree, and the grade such as in my case it is "First Division with Distinction" (i.e., First Class). For my master's degree, the final transcript states the overall grade as "A" and result as "Pass".

@EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine I applied and completed my MA, by getting a provisional degree certificate from my Bachelor's university.

At the moment it is "degree expected". The university has to make it official before it is "conferred". You can explain the situation there as you do here, of course.
If all requirements have been completed and accepted formally, then you can say that.
Most (can't guarantee all) will take it as a "provisional" proof of completion and let you move forward.
Make sure you update them when it does become official.

This thing happened to me last month: admissions for PhD positions at my University were before the final exam for MD degree.
In my case (and this is what I'd also suggest you to do) I got in touch with the secretary for PhD admissions, explained my current status, and they told me exactly what was needed. I was requested to provide a proof that said that I'm going to have the MD graduation exam the following week and state my average grade during University (in accordance to local rules). The day after MD exam, I was required to provide another proof that I passed the exam, and two weeks later, I was required to submit the complete temporary proof of me finishing my MD (the official diploma takes up to one year to arrive, and when it will arrive eventually, I'll be required to submit that also).
I want to stress again to get in touch with someone from each University you're planning to send your resume to! Some universities might have specific requirements (in my case, average grades) and as such any alternative proof you submit should contain that info.
